# How to add title,description and call to action to a video in twitter via twitter api

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am using this [endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) (statuses/update.json) to tweet a video. Where do I send title ,description and call to action parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add these values via the standard Twitter API with a media upload. You would be able to do it via the Ads API but you need to be whitelisted. See the `video_title`, `video_description`, and `video_cta` request parameters [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/creatives/api-reference/tweets#post-accounts-account-id-tweet). Alternatively, if you have access to the Media Studio dashboard, you could use that (but that would not be a programming method).